# Dimension of anihilator of subspace $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What can be the maximum dimension of the anihilator $W°$ of subspace $W= \{A^{m}; m \geq 0\}$ of vector space $V= M_{n}(R)$

Attempt:

Dim$(W°)$=Dim$(V)$- Dim$(W)$

Dim$(V)= n^{2}$

minimum dimension of $W$ should be $0$ if we take $A=O$.

So answer should be $n^{2}$.

But answer is given to be $n^{2}-1$.

Where have I gone wrong$?$

Comment: I think the point is that $A^0$ is defined to be the identity matrix, even in the case that $A = 0$.

Comment: @Ben Grossman, can we say that $A^{0} =$ I, even when $A=O?$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

Maximum possible dimension of $W°$ is $n^{2} -1$.
This is so because minimum possible dimension of $W$ is 1.As we can note , when $A=O$, $A^{0}$ is defined to be identity matrix, so dimension of $W$ is $1$ in this case. If $A$ in non zero matrix, dimension of $W$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

Hence atmost dimension of $W°$ is $n^{2}-1$.